# In Neo4j how can return a mixture of string, integer, node from server plugin

Tags: plugins, neo4j

I managed to write a working server plugin which returns only nodes.
Is it possible to write a plugin that returns a mixture of strings, integers, nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the [docs](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-plugins.html):

> ensure that it can produce an (Iterable of) Node, Relationship or Path, any Java primitive or String or an instance of a org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.Representation

So you could return a [`ListRepresentation`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/server/rest/repr/ListRepresentation.html) that contains other representations. I'm not sure if that works with a mixture of types.

Another (and preferable) option is to use a unmanaged extension instead of server plugin. They provide you much more flexibility to define request and response specifications.